# GRUB2 2 LUKS encrypted OS: attach 2nd luks os

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, grub2, luks

I setted-up ubuntu with encrypting root partition(/boot and /boot/efi are regular ones).
Then I [reduced size of this partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) and [created new encrypted](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS).
After all, I ran kali installer in expert mode, mounted 2nd partition and installed there os. It added a new EFI boot record(idk how to call it).

So if I boot to kali through bios it asks partition pass before all(I think it won't matter if I will use "central" unencrypted grub), but fails on mounting it, so I still need to run

```
cryptsetup open /dev/this this-alias
vgchange -ay
Ctrl+D
```

and only after it continues to load, but without ui(I'll try to fix it after updating grub if it won't fix automatically).

The question is: **How to add new LUKS encrypted OS to exiting grub configuration?**

PS: I tried to mount & run `update-grub`, but it only created new options for already mounted partitions so it also fails on boot(I want it to show password field, not the exception)

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://www.oxygenimpaired.com/multiple-linux-distro-installs-on-a-luks-encrypted-harddrive) amazing tutorial and just used logical volumes from different partitions.

However, I couldn't configure the grub auto chain so I hardcoded new grub partition in grub config.

```
menuentry Kali {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod chain
  set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
  chainloader (hd0,gpt3)/efi/kali/grubx64.efi
}
```

PS: it can have boot issues if you attach new disk(usb, hdd, ssd etc.)

Comment: if you were specific about where the answer would be double